# MissingPluginException while using advance_pdf_viewer flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When i try to use advance_pdf_viewer it throws an error in console

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPage on channel flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer)
E/flutter (11212): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
E/flutter (11212): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11212): #1      PDFDocument.get (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:97:18)
E/flutter (11212): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11212): #2      _PDFViewerState._loadPage (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/viewer.dart:151:18)
E/flutter (11212): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I am trying to open a pdf via link passed to my class mentioned below. Whenever I try to open the pdf it throws the above error. Please help me to fix this.

```
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class viewDoc extends StatefulWidget {
  final doc;
  final title;
  const viewDoc({@required this.doc, @required this.title, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<viewDoc> createState() => _viewDocState();
}

class _viewDocState extends State<viewDoc> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  var document;
  PDFDocument? document1;
  //final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  PDFPage? pageOne;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      document1 = await PDFDocument.fromURL(widget.doc);
      setState(() => isLoading = false);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: isLoading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : PDFViewer(document: document1!)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem in advance_pdf_viewer version  2.0.1 and is fixxed in 2.0.2, but 2.0.2 is not released yet on pub.dev (maybe in the future)

This commit fixes the bug until. Replace your advance_pdf_viewer with this in your pubspec.yaml

```
advance_pdf_viewer:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer.git
      ref: 4e5d96be29de515f1081c0b6897741b8dca84722
```

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/117
https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/110

Answer (score 2):

If the app still crashes from the solution provided by [Ozan Taskiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812524/ozan-taskiran) Try this out using the `https` version (found on the first link provided by [Ozan Taskiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5812524/ozan-taskiran))

```
advance_pdf_viewer:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer.git
    ref: 4e5d96be29de515f1081c0b6897741b8dca84722
```